# Boy watching TV and an elephant or a rabbit teddy appears on the TV and says something

Tags: story-identification, movie

I've been trying to identify this movie for years. I remember watching a bit of it as a kid. I'm not sure if the genre is horror or not.

The clip I remember is of a child, a boy I think, looking at the TV. Then an elephant or a rabbit teddy of some kind appears on the TV and says something along the lines of "If you don't find me, you will die". Then the kid screams.

I can't remember much as I saw this years ago as a kid, maybe about 15-20 years ago.

Answer (score 3):

This is a very rough guess, but there is a scene quite similar to the one you describe in the *Malcom in the Middle* Episode ["Cheerleader"](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0640301/fullcredits/) S01e12 (first telecasted in 2000)

Dewey wants to have a blue elephant teddy called Herbie. When watching the commercial he dreams the teddy says:

> All of the boys and girls on your street are my friends.
> They all bought me.
> Your parents have lots of money.
> They're just hiding it.
> But I don't want you to buy me for me.
> It's for your own good.
> **I didn't want to tell you this, but if you don't buy me, you'll die.**